# how to write RegEx on non-ascii range using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, utf-8

My Input Was :

> This is a simple text just for test purpose only ascii text
>   12345678910-=[];'#/.,- with new regexxx ! " £ $ % ^ &
>   * ( )
>   _
>   + { }~@:<>?|Asdf –jkll

Now I am using JSON to decode my input data which decodes(html type of response ex: &nbsp,\x{a3},&gt etc...) it as follows:

> This is a simple text just for test purpose only ascii text12345678910-=[];\'#/.,\\-with new regexxx!\"\u00A3$%^&*()_+{}~@:<>?|
> Asdf \u2013jkll
> "

Now I am sending this decoded data to my Program to replace this unicode(utf-8) and other non-ascii characters with space/or some printable characters(I mean i want to print only ascii range characters)
So, I tried all of the following in perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use utf8;
#Due to some security reasons I am not mentioning the url,hope u understand
my $ResRef = sendHTTPRequest($someurlRequest);
my $string = $ResRef->decoded_content;#I used json decode to decode content

my $string = transalte_replace($string);

sub transalte_replace {
my $string = shift;
    for($string) {
      s/\\u[0-9]+/1-/g;
      s/\\u[a-zA-Z0-9\+]*/2-/g;
      s/\\x\{[a-zA-Z0-9]*\}/3-/g;
      s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g;
      s/[^\u0000-\u007F]+/replace1/g;
      s/[^\x00-\x7F]+/rep/g;
      s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g;
      s/[^A-Za-z0-9\.,\?'""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:\<\>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`\~]+/y/g;
      #s/[£]//g;
      s/[^\x20-\x7E]+/replace3/g;
      #s/\\u[0-9]+/2-/g;
      #s/\\x[a-z0-9]+/3-/g;
      #s/[^\x00-\x7F]/4-/g;
    }
}
```

The output still is:

> "This is a simple text just for test purpose only ascii
>   text12345678910-=[];'#/.,\-with new
>   regexxx!\"\x{a3}\$%^&*()_+{}~\@:?|Asdf \x{2013}jkll";

**I am working on Windows Environment, I want only ascii range characters,numbers and symbols and nothing else.Please help**

Comment: I think - based on your last question - that it actually did, but you're escaping your unicode strings. But I would suggest that some sample data that you're trying to 'clean' is necessary to give you a good answer.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.What does it mean by escaping unicode strings i didnot get it.NOW I AM NOT EVEN ENCODING MY STRING IN qq.

Comment: My Input is my $string = ¬`\|!"£$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?,./;'#[]=-0987654321:-+>< and after decoding i sent it to regex(which you have given me) and output still has x{a3} and x{ac} etc...

Comment: That should be edited into your question. However: `my $str = "\x{ac}\x{a3}";
$str =~ s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g;
print $str;` - this prints: `--`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, *runnable* demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Hi Sobrique, sorry was midnight for so dnt provide any update.I tried your line(s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g) but it didn't work for me. I am trying hard with different solutions but nothing is working for me:(

Comment: You still haven't shown us the actual input you're working with. It's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong if you don't give us the input and a problem description that's more than just "nothing is working".

Comment: I am telling truth my task is to convert any non-ascii to space and the input is anything for example: This is a simple text just for test purpose only ascii text12345678910-=[];\'#/.,\\-with new regexxx!\"\u00A3$%^&*()_+{}~@:<>?|
Asdf \u2013jkll
"

Comment: My input generally is in html format as I query results from url link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g
```

is equivalent to

```
s/[^\x00-\x7F]/-/g
```

so it couldn't possibly leave `AC` and `A3` unchanged.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;                             # Source code encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal produces/expects UTF-8.
use feature qw( say );

my $string = q{¬`\\|!"£$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?,./;'#[]=-0987654321:-+><};
say sprintf '%1$vX %1$s', $string;
$string =~ s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g;
say sprintf '%1$vX %1$s', $string;
```

Output:

```
$ perl a.pl
AC.60.5C.7C.21.22.A3.24.25.[...] ¬`\|!"£$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?,./;'#[]=-0987654321:-+><
2D.60.5C.7C.21.22.2D.24.25.[...] -`\|!"-$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?,./;'#[]=-0987654321:-+><
^^                ^^             ^     ^
```

Did you apply the `s///` operator to the right variable?

Comment: I am working in windows os environment and i donot know why it is working for you and not for me is it because you are on linux?

Comment: I am now editing my question to show my input ,my code and output

Comment: On Windows, the console would expect something other than UTF-8, so you'd have to the `use open` line, but that it'll still work (even without fixing the line). As for your updated code, it's still not runnable.

Comment: HI I think we figured out the problem occurs while json is decoding itself .json i think is unable to decode and fails at that point. I am taking decoded content to fix the issue but that is not the problem .Thanks to all who contributed here. I learned so much.

Comment: I think all of your answers are correct but the problem is with json decoding. So thank you all

Comment: Your question had nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Ya initially when i got the issue i thought my regex is giving this error but later i have realised that it is json... It is a very complex script and it was to get my head around it.... anyway thank you.I learned regex aswell.